# Running Bigquery query uncached using Python API

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Hi I am using BigQuery and with its Python API submitting Queries to get results. I am using the method - bqclient.query("PASS THE QUERY") to execute the query programmatically. I am trying to do a performance test but BigQuery returns cached results. Is there a way I can set cache = False in the Python API while calling the bqclient.query method. Through the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#bigquery-query-cache-api) I have see that we can set useQueryCache property to false, but am not sure where to set it.

Current Code

```
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = bigquery.query(select_query, job_config = job_config)
```

query represents the query that I want to run.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `useQueryCache`. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query) for more info. Not the lower case underscore format:

```
[..]
QUERY = ('SELECT ..')
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.use_query_cache = False
query_job = client.query(QUERY, job_config=job_config)
[..]
```

Comment: Hi Graham, in this line query_job = bigquery.query(QUERY, job_config=job_config), I think bigquery does not have a function query, it is throwing an error. `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` Any thoughts on how to call the job after setting the query_cache to false

Comment: @PramodSripada - please post your code in the question